# syntax issue ? passing objects as parameters in neo4j cypher statement

Tags: rest, neo4j, parameter-passing, cypher

I am running a query like this using the REST API to the transaction endpoint:

```
{
   "statements" : [{"statement":"MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE id(n) IN {diagramnodes}  return     [type(r),labels(m)] ",
   "parameters" :{
       "diagramnodes" : [28]
    }}]
}
```

which returns the expected result:

```
{
"commit": "http://myserver:7474/db/data/transaction/542/commit",
"results": [
    {
        "columns": [
            "[type(r),labels(m)]"
        ],
        "data": [
            {
                "row": [
                    [
                        "CONTAINS",
                        [
                            "Sentence"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "row": [
                    [
                        "CONTAINS",
                        [
                            "Prologram",
                            "Diagram"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },

            .......
        ]
    }
],
"transaction": {
    "expires": "Sun, 07 Sep 2014 17:50:11 +0000"
},
"errors": []
}
```

When adding another parameter and a filter to limit the types of rels that are returned:

```
{"statements": [{
"statement": "MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) WHERE id(n) IN {diagramnodes} AND [type(r),labels(m)] IN {includerels} return r ",
"parameters": {
    "diagramnodes": [28],
    "includerels": [
        [
            "CONTAINS",
            [
                "Prologram",
                "Diagram"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "HAS_TARGET",
            ["Term"]
        ]
    ]
}
}]}
```

it does not return any results. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, by concatenating the reltype and labels, and comparing it to a collection of primitive types. This is the cypher (added some CRLF to make it easier to read)

```
{
"statements" : [{"statement":"

MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) 
WHERE id(n) IN {diagramnodes} 
WITH type(r) as rtype, REDUCE(acc = '', p IN labels(m)| acc + ' '+ p) AS mlabels,m 
WITH rtype+mlabels As rtypemlabels,m 
WHERE rtypemlabels IN {includerels}  
RETURN rtypemlabels,id(m) ",

"parameters" :{
"diagramnodes" : [28],
"includerels": ["HAS_TARGET Term","CONTAINS Sentence","CONTAINS Prologram Diagram"]
}}]
}
```

Note 1 : type(r)+REDUCE(acc = '', p IN labels(m)| acc + ' '+ p)  does not work, you have to insert an additional WITH
Note 2 : comparing a collection of nested objects with an IN clause should be possible and remains on my wish list. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`IN` operations very probably only work for collections of primitive values.

what you can try to do is to rewrite it into `ALL(x in coll WHERE expr(x))` predicate.

for an input like:

```
[["CONTAINS",["Prologram","Diagram"]],
 ["HAS_TARGET",["Term"]]]
```

you can try:

```
ALL(entry in {includerels} WHERE type(r) = entry[0] AND ALL(l in labels(n) WHERE l in entry[1]))
```

Comment: Hi @michael-hunger , thanks. Although I haven't got it to work, I guess your suggestion does not prevent matches in which there is a partial match, i.e. when labels(m) = A,B and the includerels contains "KNOWS",[A,B,C]. I found another workaround that I will post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNWIND on your parameters array instead of using IN. Depending on your data, you might have to use DISTINCT as well. But UNWIND works well for me.